# Storage of website analytical data - relational or time series?

Tags: sql, database, time-series, analytics

We have a requirement to store website analytical data (think: views on a page, interactions, etc). Note: this is seperate to Google Analytics data, as we want to own the data and enrich it as we see fit.

Storage requirements:

- each 'event' will have a timestamp, event type and some other metadata (user id, etc)
- the storage is append only. No updates or deletes
- writes are consistent, but not IOT scale. Maybe, 50/sec
- estimating growth of about 100 million rows a year

Query requirements:

- graphing data *cumulatively* over a period of time
- slice/filter data by all the metadata as well as day/week/month/year slices
- will likely need to be integrated into a larger data warehouse

Question: Is this a no brainer for a time series DB like InfluxDB,or can I get away with a well tuned SQL server table?